# How to programmatically open Run c++?

Tags: c++, shellexecute

the question is how to open Run programmatically from c++? I know that have some function that can replace that, like shellexec, winexec but for some task I need just Run dialog to appear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Run Dialog is located in shell32.dll using the function `RunFileDlg`. One way show the dialog is to use rundll32.exe to invoke that function. Execute the following command using the `CreateProcess` Win32 API:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,#61
```

(where #61 is the ordinal number of the `RunFileDlg` function).

Reference for shell32.dll functions: http://www.geoffchappell.com/viewer.htm?doc=studies/windows/shell/shell32/api/index.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: thnx ... all for replay, it help's a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Use shellexec, winexec or any other favorite function to execute

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,#61
```

This will open the dialog.

Comment: Ha! You were exactly 1 second faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
#include <cstdlib>

system("rundll32.exe shell32.dll,#61");
```