# How to start windows "run" dialog from C#

Tags: c#, windows, process, dialog

I want to start the run dialog (Windows+R) from Windows within my C# code.

I assume this can be done using explorer.exe but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Is there a reason you want the "Run" box instead of starting the process directly through Process.Start?

Comment: I have a very strong suspicion this is a "[Shoe or Bottle?](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx)" question.

Comment: I understand you want to fire up the "Run" command provided by the Windows Explorer. Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @user1216595 and that reason is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `RunFileDlg` API is unsupported and may be removed by Microsoft from future versions of Windows (I'll grant that MS's commitment to backwards compatibility and the fact that this API, though undocumented, appears to be fairly widely known makes this unlikely, but it's still a possibility).

The supported way to launch the run dialog is using the [`IShellDispatch::FileRun`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537715.aspx) method.

In C#, you can access this method by going to Add Reference, select the COM tab, and select "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation". After doing this you can launch the dialog as follows:

```
Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
shell.FileRun();
```

Yes, the `RunFileDlg` API offers more customizability, but this has the advantage of being documented, supported, and therefore unlikely to break in the future.

Note that Shell32 must be run on an STA thread. If you get an exception in your code, add `[STAThread]` above your method declaration like this, for example:

```
    [STAThread]
    private static void OpenRun() {
        //Shell32 code here
    }
```

Any method calling a method that uses Shell32 should also be run on an STA thread.

Answer (score 9):

Use RunFileDlg:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#61", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int RunFileDlg(
    [In] IntPtr hWnd,
    [In] IntPtr icon,
    [In] string path,
    [In] string title,
    [In] string prompt,
    [In] uint flags);

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // You might also want to add title, window handle...etc.
    RunFileDlg(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, null, 0);
}
```

Possible values for `flags`:

```
RFF_NOBROWSE = 1; //Removes the browse button.
RFF_NODEFAULT = 2; // No default item selected.
RFF_CALCDIRECTORY = 4; // Calculates the working directory from the file name.
RFF_NOLABEL = 8; // Removes the edit box label.
RFF_NOSEPARATEMEM = 14; // Removes the Separate Memory Space check box (Windows NT only).
```

See also [How to programmatically open Run c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356270/how-to-programmatically-open-run-c)

Comment: Note that technically this is undocumented

Comment: Is this a undocumented call? I could not find any refrence to this on the MSDN or on http://pinvoke.net

Comment: I have doubts #61 remains stable over future releases.

Comment: Do note that `RunFileDlg` is an undocumented function, which means that Microsoft may change its behaviour or remove it entirely at any time. The supported way is to use `IShellDispatch::FileRun()`, which can be accessed in C# by adding a reference to the COM library "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation" and running `var shell = new Shell32.Shell(); shell.FileRun();`.

Answer (score 2):

Another method would be to emulate the Windows+R key combination.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class KeyboardSend
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
    private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;

    public static void KeyDown(Keys vKey)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    }

    public static void KeyUp(Keys vKey)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
}
```

and call:

```
KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.LWin);
KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.R);
KeyboardSend.KeyUp(Keys.R);
KeyboardSend.KeyUp(Keys.LWin);
```