# how run "RUN-command" in windowsAPI

Tags: c#, winapi, findwindow, findwindowex

I working now with WINAPI and I try to run the app "RUN-command"
I tried to do FINDWINDOW / FINDWINDOWEX but it does not make sense because the program "RUN" is not working yet.
How to open the "Run-command"?

Comment: This may be because Run isn't actually a program.  If you're looking to start a program from your C# app, there are other ways of doing it.

Comment: Are you talking about the run-command? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command

Comment: If you want the open the *Run Dialog* see [Start “Run” Process with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331088/start-run-process-with-c-sharp)

Comment: @KorenLeven, I believe AlexK's comment to be what you're after.