# C# Sendkeys ALT + SHIFT

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I want to call the Switch language options on Windows, basically pressing the key ALT + SHIFT
from C#.
I read the answer from here [How to start windows "run" dialog from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331088/how-to-start-windows-run-dialog-from-c-sharp)

This is what I have tried so far

```
//KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.Alt);
//KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.LShiftKey);
//KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.Alt);
//KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.LShiftKey);
```

Also

```
SendKeys.Send("%+")
```

If you press ALT + SHIFT you will understand what I'm trying to achive

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solve this issue, following the link on my question

```cs
static class KeyboardSend
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

   private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
   private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;

   public static void KeyDown(Keys vKey)
   {
       keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
   }

   public static void KeyUp(Keys vKey)
   {
       keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
   }
}
```

Then calling like this:

```cs
KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.LWin);
KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.R);
KeyboardSend.KeyUp(Keys.R);
KeyboardSend.KeyUp(Keys.LWin);
```